# How to disable style inherit from parent element

Tags: html, css

Width in in parent table is automatically inherited to child table.

**HTML**

```
<table class="datagrid">
    <tr><td>sdfdsfds</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
             <table class="gridpager">
             <tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>1</td></tr>
             </table>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.datagrid table {
    width: 100%; 
}

.gridpager table {
    float: right;
}
```

If i add width:auto in gridpager class it will works.but need to override all style of parent in child class.Is there any other solution other than this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the css changes like following

```
table.datagrid {
    width: 100%; 
}

table.gridpager {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: please post example on jsfiddle

Comment: It works fine. Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Luvfyu2f/